# Drop-Downs on Fixie

Tags: handlebars

Does anyone know if using drop-downs on a fixie every becomes problematic.

I just bought a rather heavy drop down bar set; I go back in forth between single speed and fixed. I love riding with them on single speed and find it awesome using the drops on straight aways, and just riding the tops when I have to brake a lot in traffic in such.

I haven't flipped to fixed wheel within them yet; I'm wondering if it's a good idea to ride / commute in fixed with this handlebar set. Just curious on thoughts. Am I setting myself up for some somersaults on brake, haha.

I'm NYC; and commute around 18 miles a day round trip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I commute 12 miles a day to work on a track bike with drops and have never had a problem. The real advice is: if they work for you, they work. If you find it uncomfortable or inefficient, switch. Get your wheel flipped and enjoy the ride!

As a sidenote, I'd recommend keeping both your brakes on. Otherwise, you could end up somersaulting.

Comment: Totally agree. You'll probably find in the city that you spend most of the time on the hoods anyway, traffic, lights etc. But I find the drops useful if I take my fixie out at the weekend. +1 @klonesy for mentioning keeping the brakes....suicide otherwise I reckon

Comment: I also agree with keeping the brakes on.  Not only do they give you another hand position, they also allow you to have harder gearing on your fixie.  If you only have 1 brake , then the pedals are your back-up brake.  So you have to have gearing low enough such that you can stop even when going at high speeds.

Answer (score 2):

I commute on a fixie with drop bars ( just like klonesy ), and I find that it's actually easier to shift your weight around than with just a flat bar, and easier to brake harder and prevent said somersaults.

Answer (score 0):

I only enjoy drop bars on long rides. In traffic, around the city it's all about the bullhorn handlebars. You can dig in, accelerate faster,get more power, and keep up with traffic on bullhorns. If you're backpedaling to brake or if use pedal straps and like to lock and skid-stop, bullhorns are the way to go. Fixed gear in a city is the best.